# Why is my while loop not terminating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to complete an assignment regarding pygame for my computer programming class; I'm not particularly well versed in this kind of thing, so excuse me if I make some mistakes when asking my question.

I'm trying to modify some source code from our textbook, with the goal of allowing the user to set what speed a group of blocks move in a window, as well as the delay between position updates. In the beginning of the program is a while loop, designed to let the user pick between predetermined settings, or create their own.

```
choice = ""
while choice != "E" or "e" or "Elect" or "elect" or "ELECT" or "C" or "c" or "Create" or "create" or "CREATE" :
    choice = input("Would you like to elect a speed setting for the vectors, or create your own? (Type 'E' for elect or 'C' for create) ")
```

When I tried running the program in the shell, upon typing 'e', it gave me the input statement for the while loop again. Why is 'choice' not being set to my input?

Comment: Try `while choice not in ("e", "E", "elect" ...):`

Comment: Even better cast your input to lower case and only check one case type: `choice not in ("e", "elect", "c", "create")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
choice = ""
while choice.lower() not in ("e", "elect", "c", "create"):
    choice = input("Would you like to elect a speed setting for the vectors,, create your own? (Type 'E' for elect, 'C' for create) ")
```

**WHY**

The problem you have is `choice != "E" or "e" or ...` means `(choice != "E") or ("e") or (...)`. And `"e"` evaluates to `True` since it not `None`, `0`, `False`, or an empty sequence. So your conditional is ALWAYS true.

Comment: You can simplify this by using `lower`

Comment: @Slayer Alright, done.

Comment: I think it would be useful to explain why the code in the question doesn't work

Comment: @Prof Done. Wow, you comment faster than I edit :-)

Comment: Thanks! That saved me from a headache. I'll never know why some things in python don't work the way I think they will, but at least I can understand enough to get through this class.

Comment: @KalebMyers Good luck with your class. Python is fun.

Answer (score 2):

`if choice != "E" or "e"` can be explicitly translated to `if (choice != "E") or ("e")`. In other words, regardless of whether `choice != "E"` is true or false, the overall expression always returns `True` as `"e"` is not an empty string so always evaluates to `True`.

```
>>> if True or "e":
...     print("entered")
entered

>>> if False or "e":
...     print("entered")
entered
```

What you should do instead is:

```
while choice.lower() not in ("e", "elect", "c", "create"):
```

Answer (score 1):

Your other `or`'s evaluate to True. So, you're while condition breaks down to `while choice != 'E' or True` which isn't going to terminate. You need to use `if choice != 'string'` repeatedly, or preferrably you can just check `while choice not in list_of_bad_strings`

Comment: Oh, I think I understand that; you're saying:
if choice != 'string' or choice != 'string" or choice != 'string'....
Right?